# Swap Fusion Drive for SSD

Tags: fusion-drive

I want to swap my Fusion Drive for a 1 TB SSD, to gain more speed loading programs. Do I have to delete (uninstall) the Fusion Drive first or can I just take out the HD and install the SSD and then start to format and install Sierra.

Will I the have afterwards 2 SSD's....the old one (128 GB) and the new one (1 TB)? Of course I have backups!

Comment: I assume it's a new 1 TB SSD (instead of a 1 GB one - which would be a bad deal)  and edited your question!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to this is YES.

I have done this exact thing in my iMac and it works perfectly.  You don't have to "uninstall" the Fusion drive.  Once you remove the HDD, you would have effectively destroyed the Fusion drive requiring the original (128GB) SSD to be reformatted.

I personally opted to create a new Fusion drive of the 128GB and 1TB Fusion drive for a 1.128TB drive, but you for format them and use them independently as well.